# Slow MySQL database query time in a Python for loop

Tags: python, mysql, pandas, eclipse, pydev

I have a task to run 8 equal queries (1 query per 1 country) and doing so return data from MySQL database. The reason I can't run 1 query with all countries in one is that each country needs to have different column names. Also, results need to be updated daily with a dynamic date range (last 7 days). Yes, I could run all countries and do the column naming and everything with Pandas but I thought that the following solution would be more efficient. So, my solution was to create a for loop that uses predefined lists with all the countries their respective dimensions and date range variables that change according to the current date. The problem I'm having is that MySQL query running in the loop takes so much more time than if I run the same query directly in our data warehouse (~140-500 seconds vs. 30 seconds). The solution works with smaller tables from DWH. The things is that I don't know which part exactly is causing the problem and how to solve it.

Here is an example of my code with some smaller "tests" implemented in it:

```
#Import libraries:
from google.cloud import storage
from google.oauth2 import service_account
import mysql.connector
import pandas as pd
import time
from datetime import timedelta, date

#Create a connection to new DWH:
coon = mysql.connector.connect(
  host="the host goes here",
  user="the user goes here",
  passwd="the password goes here"
)

#Create Google Cloud Service credential references:
credentials = service_account.Credentials.from_service_account_file(r'C:\Users\ivo.vancans\OneDrive\Documents\Python Workspace\my credential json goes here.json')
project_id='my project id goes here'

cursor = coon.cursor()

#Create lists of countries and dimensions
countries = ['EE','FI','LV','LT']
appp_id_dim = ['ga:dimension5','ga:dimension5','ga:dimension5','ga:dimension5']
status_dim = ['ga:dimension21','ga:dimension12','ga:dimension20','ga:dimension15']
score_dim = ['ga:dimension11','ga:dimension11','ga:dimension19','ga:dimension14']

#Define the current date and date that was 7 days before current date:
date_now = date.today() - timedelta(days=1)
date_7d_prev = date_now - timedelta(days=7)

#Create a loop
for c,s in zip(countries, score_dim):
    start_time = time.time()
    #Create the query using string formating:
    query = f"""select ca.ID, sv.subType, SUM(svl.score) as '{s}'
    from aio.CreditApplication ca
    join aio.ScoringResult sr 
    on sr.creditApplication_ID = ca.ID 
    join aio.ScorecardVariableLine svl 
    on svl.id = sr.scorecardVariableLine_ID
    join aio.ScorecardVariable sv 
    on sv.ID = svl.scorecardVariable_ID
    where sv.country='{c}'  
    #and sv.subType ="asc"
    and sv.subType != 'fsc'
    and sr.created >= '2020-01-01'
    and sr.created between '{date_7d_prev} 00:00:00' and '{date_now} 23:59:59'
    group by ca.id,sv.subType"""

    #Check of sql query
    print('query is done', time.time()-start_time)

    start_time = time.time()
    sql = pd.read_sql_query(query, coon)
    #check of assigning sql:
    print ('sql is assigned',time.time()-start_time)

    start_time = time.time()
    df = pd.DataFrame(sql
                      #, columns = ['created','ID','state']
                      )
    #Check the df assignment:
    print ('df has been assigned', time.time()-start_time)

    #Create a .csv file from the final dataframe:
    start_time = time.time()
    df.to_csv(fr"C:\Users\ivo.vancans\OneDrive\Documents\Python Workspace\Testing Ground\{c}_sql_loop_test.csv", index = False, header=True, encoding='utf-8', sep=';')
    #Check csv file creation:
    print ('csv has been created',time.time()-start_time)

    #Close the session
    start_time = time.time()
    cursor.close()

    #Check the session closing:
    print('The cursor is closed',time.time()-start_time)
```

This example has 4 countries because I tried cutting the amount in half but that doesn't help also. That was me thinking that I have some sort of query restrictions on the DWH end because major slow down always started with the 5th country. Running them separately takes almost the same time for each but it still takes too long.
So, my tests show that the loop always lags at the step of querying data. Every other step takes less than a second, but querying time goes up to 140-500, sometimes even more, seconds as mentioned previously. So, what do you think is the problem?

Comment: Is it still the last query that takes up most of the time if you change the sequence of requests around? `EXPLAIN <query>` is what you'd normally use in MySQL to give you details about how the query is being run, so you can see any missing indexes, etc. I'd also suggest [using an actual profiler](https://docs.python.org/3/library/profile.html) to get feedback of what your application is doing next time; it takes much of the guesswork out (it will also be able to tell you where the time is spent inside the different python modules).

Comment: Thanks for the comment. By changing the sequence you mean what? Which country goes first? If so, yes.. that doesn't matter in general. Some countries hold more rows of data but still, speed with Python solution vs. simply running the query with an sql client on dwh is slower.

Comment: Since it's the last one that's taking up most of the time according to your post, regardless of the sequence of the queries, seem to indicate something server side; but a profiler should be able to give you more details - at least to see if it's the actual `read_sql_query` that takes time. I'd also try to print out the query itself and make sure that it's the same query as you expect (i.e. the query you're running manually). But yes, there might be limiting factors from DWH.

Comment: I did the thing with printing out query and copy-paste-run it on dwh, works just fine. I'll now look into the profiler you suggested.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the solution! After talking to a person in my company who has a lot more experience with SQL and our particular DWH engine, he agreed to help and rewrote the SQL part. Instead of left joining a subquery, I had to rewrite it so that there would be no subquery. Why? Because our particular engine doesn't create an index for subquery, bet separately joined tables will have indexes. That improved the time of the whole script dramatically, from ~40 minutes run time to ~ less than 1 minute.